# Max date for every month

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, denodo

In the following you can see an example of my table:

```
test_id     test_date     test_date_from    cash_per_step
1           2020-01-01    2019-12-30        30
1           2020-01-21    2019-12-30        40
1           2020-02-28    2019-12-30        30
2           2020-01-01    2019-12-30        30
2           2020-01-21    2019-12-30        40
2           2020-02-28    2019-12-30        30
```

As you can see, there is no unique ID (unfortunately I cannot change it either).
I want to create a view that ONLY contains the rows that contain the MAX (test_date) for each MONTH for every test_id!

So like this:

```
test_id     test_date     test_date_from    cash_per_step
1           2020-01-21    2019-12-30        40
1           2020-02-28    2019-12-30        30
2           2020-01-21    2019-12-30        40
2           2020-02-28    2019-12-30        30
```

The data is only test data, please excuse that it is double. I am only interested in the functionality of the query.

Comment: MySQL or SQL Server? They are totally different products...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in both MySQL (8.0+) and SQL Server.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    test_id,
    FIRST_VALUE(test_date) OVER (PARTITION BY test_id,MONTH(test_date), YEAR(test_date) 
                                 ORDER BY test_date desc ) as test_date,
    FIRST_VALUE(test_date_from) OVER (PARTITION BY test_id,MONTH(test_date), YEAR(test_date) 
                                      ORDER BY test_date desc ) as test_date_from,
    FIRST_VALUE(cash_per_step) OVER (PARTITION BY test_id,MONTH(test_date), YEAR(test_date) 
                                     ORDER BY test_date desc ) as cash_per_step
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

This produces the same results even though it looks like basic code:

```
declare @table table (test_id int,test_date date,test_date_from date,cash_per_step float)

insert into @table

(test_id,test_date,test_date_from,cash_per_step)
values
    (1,'2020-01-01','2019-12-30',30)
,   (1,'2020-01-21','2019-12-30',40)
,   (1,'2020-02-28','2019-12-30',30)
,   (2,'2020-01-01','2019-12-30',30)
,   (2,'2020-01-21','2019-12-30',40)
,   (2,'2020-02-28','2019-12-30',30);

select
    test_id
,   max(test_date)  test_date
,   test_date_from
,   cash_per_step
from    @table
group by test_id,cash_per_step,test_date_from
order by test_id,test_date
```

Results:

[image: Expected Results]

See [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6e9da5e30085618a14351131db804eab)

Answer (score -1):

```sql
;WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT *, 
         ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),test_date),1,7), 
         test_id ORDER BY TEST_ID,TEST_DATE DESC) RN 
  FROM @table
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN =1 ORDER BY TEST_ID
```